# `text-decoration` behaviour in `button`

Tags: html, css

Within the same `button`, I am trying to display text with an underline and some without.

My markup is currently looks like this:

```css
.button-underline {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-underline">
  Text with underline
  <span class="no-underline">Text with no underline</span>
</button>
```

I expected "Text with no underline" to render with no underline. However, this doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: use inline-block instead of block

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `<span>` is wrapped inside of your `<button>`. The button's `text-decoration` property will underline all children, meaning the `span` itself doesn't have a text decoration property, however the button still underlines it.

To fix this, you can wrap all other elements inside of the button inside of a `button-underline` class and select those with CSS.

```css
.button-underline {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.button-underline .no-underline {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<button>
    <p class="button-underline">Text with underline</p>
    <span class="no-underline">Text with no underline</span>
</button>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Are you able to explain to me why `<button>` underlines all its children in my original example? I would have thought the specificity of the span's `class` (`.no-underline`) would outweigh the button's `class` and I can't figure out why it doesn't.